# What happened to Apps Marketplace for domain only private listings?

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

The documentation for publishing an app to Google Apps Marketplace states that private listings will appear in the "For yourdomain.com" section of the Google Apps Marketplace.  There does not appear to be a section called that in the new marketplace UI.  Am I missing something obvious or is this no longer supported?  I am trying to publish an app to a few trusted testers before fully releasing.

Link to the relevant documentation:
https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/listing#domain-only_private_apps

Thanks,

Jeremy

Answer (score 0):

If your marketplace is private, only logged-in users can see the content. Users who are logged-in will see the homepage where you can customize some content to explain the situation.

It is useful to keep a marketplace private, so visitors who are not users can't view it content. This us useful if you want to preserve privacy or keep your [marketplace](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/listing) content `hidden` to the world.